# Confluent platform vs Debezium

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium

I'm trying to use Debezium platform to make a Kafka-cdc.But I was confused.
What is really difference between Confluent platform and Debezium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confluent (https://www.confluent.io/) is a platform which mainly integrate Apache-Kafka (https://kafka.apache.org/) and its ecosystems. So let say the basic Confluent platform has Zookeeper, apache kafka, KSql and thier Control Center.

Debezium is another platform to focus Database Streaming.

So you think Confluent is the general Streaming, and Debezium actually has a connector https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/index.html that can be integreted to Confluent like in https://www.confluent.io/hub/debezium/debezium-connector-postgresql

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing, Confluent Platform does not have any CDC connectors, and you don't really need it. Apache Kafka Connect that is bundled as part of the Confluent Platform is all that's needed, and can be downloaded directly from Apache Kafka site instead.

Debezium is built on Kafka Connect API, and provided as a plug in.

Comment: hey @OneCricketeer so what is the relation between https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-oracle-cdc/current/overview.html and Debezium ?

Comment: @MaatDeamon I think that was Confluent's effort at a cash-grab (it's a [enterprise connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-oracle-cdc/current/overview.html#license)) to support customers with Oracle databases. Meanwhile, Debezium is OSS